# css sheets not applied in java web project

Tags: html, css, netbeans-8

I am using for the first time Java Web in Netbeans IDE 8.0.2, 
I've added the css sheets in an assets folder at the same level as WEB-INF under Web Pages directory, and I included them as follow:

```
<link href="./assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I also tried: `<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

But for some reason, my pages are displayed as if there's no css sheets
How should I include them in another way? Or is there something I need to add?

Thank you

Comment: what happens if you full the path above on the browser? are you able to get to the CSS file?

Comment: No! I am getting HTTP status 404 Not Found.

Comment: then the file is not copied to the 'deployment' folder... I do not use NetBeans IDE but how are you deploying your app? (in WAR format? or exploded mode?) - if WAR, ensure your CSS path is added to the build path;

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Netbeans, but have you tried using the style tag or the style attribute? If the style tag works you probably have a typo in your file directory.

```
<style>p{color:red;}</style>
<p style="color: red;"></p>
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it's working, so I think my problem is in the path it cannot be a typo, but I cant seem to fix it. Thank you

Comment: after looking at your post again your link is wrong
it should be `../assets/css/style.css`
it needs two periods

Comment: I really didn't know what the problem was, i just clean and build the project and it worked! Weiirrd